# How to calibrate RGBD camera position under ROS2?

Tags: ros2, moveit, tf2, camera-calibration, realsense

I have a RealSense RGBD camera mounted on a robot's end-effector and would like to calibrate the camera's position relative to said end-effector under ROS2. I am using the [moveit hand-eye calibration package](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/hand_eye_calibration/hand_eye_calibration_tutorial.html), more specifically [this port for ROS2](https://github.com/AndrejOrsula/moveit2_calibration).

The camera drivers define a "camera base" frame which is parent to the "depth" and "rgb" cameras in the RealSense device. The TF2 tree looks like this:

[image: TF2 tree for the question]

The camera calibration can determine the transform between the `EE_frame` and `rgb_optical` frames, however this does not allow me to complete the tree as it violates the "one parent per frame" limit of TF2. **How could I go about recovering the transform between `EE_frame` and `camera_base`** given that the images used for calibration are in `rgb_optical`? Ideally without manually inverting and composing the camera transforms. Is there another package that works with ROS2 and would allow to perform this calibration?